# php function advice needed

Tags: php, function, strip-tags

any advice would be helpful, thank you

i'm trying to clean a piece of html tags with contents but for some reason it's not working properly

```
<?php

function cleaning($vclean)
{
$vclean = strip_tags($vclean);
$vclean = rtrim($vclean);
$vclean = trim($vclean);

$vclean = str_replace("  ", "", $vclean);
$vclean = preg_replace('/\s\s+/', ' ', $vclean);
$vclean = str_replace("'", "", $vclean);

echo "function is cleaning<br>";

}


cleaning($any_variable);


?>
```

Comment: how do you know it's not working? You're not echoing or returning any results

Comment: We need more information than "it's not working properly".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you are expecting the function to clean the original variable?

Like:

```
$variable = '<p>foobar</p>';
cleaning($variable);
echo $variable;
```

This does not work, because the function cannot 'see' or change a variable that is declared outside the function. Because of that, you will see the old value of $variable, not the cleaned one.

If this is the case, you should read about [Variable scopes](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php)

As for the practical solution, you should `return` the cleaned variable in the end of the function, and do the following:

```
$variable = '<p>foobar</p>';
$variable = cleaning($variable);
echo $variable;
```

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you were intending:

```
<?php

function cleaning($vclean)
{
$vclean = strip_tags($vclean);
$vclean = rtrim($vclean);
$vclean = trim($vclean);

$vclean = str_replace("  ", "", $vclean);
$vclean = preg_replace('/\s\s+/', ' ', $vclean);
$vclean = str_replace("'", "", $vclean);

return $vclean;

}


echo cleaning("function is cleaning<br>");


?>
```